# Jquery form on change except one element

Tags: jquery

I have this html

```
  <form id="Numbers">
      <select name="Type" id="Type">
          <option value="1">1</value>
          <option value="2">3</value>
          <option value="3">3</value>
      <select>
      <input name="SomeText">
      <input type="submit"> 
  </form>
```

And this jquery:

```
$(document).on("change submit", "#Numbers", function () {   
    //Do things and submit 
});
```

Can I somehow detect which field was changed so that if I have a second function where Type is the id of a select field inside the form Numbers:

```
$(document).on("change", "#Type", function () { 
       //Do different things and submit 
    });
```

I want to set it up in a way that they won't both fire.

Or I probably need something like

```
$(document).on("change submit", "#Numbers", function () {  
    //Do things and submit 

   if(changed child is #Type)
   {}
   else
   {}
});
```

But I don't know the proper syntax.

Comment: how come both will fire?? Id is unique right per element???

Comment: "Numbers" is a form, the function triggers when any child element changes and "Type" is a child element of that form, but I want a slightly different action when "Type" changes.

Comment: You should post HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not understood wrongly you need to capture change event of all elements inside the form and then for specific element you want to trigger separate event to some operation. Here is what I've written in Fiddler [Capture element id](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/16766/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').on('change',function(event){
    alert(event.target.id);
    });  
});



 <form id='test'>
    <input type='text' id='text0' />
    <input type="text" id='text1'/>
 </form>
```

using **event.target.id** you can do other operation with the element or you can redirect the call to other jquery function.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed, I added `if(event.target.id == "Type" ) {}` to the first function and removed the second function.